# MousePressed and MouseReleased refers to same component

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have made a little program like the old fashion paint.
Everything works so far without any issues but now I have tried to implement a Rectangle drawer so that when a button is pushed to draw a rectangle the next press and release of the mouse button will draw a rectangle instead of the usual just paint a label to a specific color.

I have a class Pixel that stores a Label and a some other things like coordinates.

I have a bunch of these Pixel object in a 2D array which is then added to a Gridlayout.

I have a controller class that hold all the listeners and I had a big method where I added the writer listener which what a MouseAdepter which implemented MousePressed, MouseReleased and MouseEntered.

Now when drawing the a rectangle and you need to push a button to activate this which triggers a boolean which I use for this and that is working.

However now when I use this function this is what happens:
I get the correct label when pressing the mouse which for exemple could be on position x = 4, y = 4.
But when I then drag the mouse away a bit and released the mouse I get the same label on the same position x = 4, y = 4.

I have tried to but these in seperate listeners now in different methods and calling them all in start of program as before but know divided.

Here is the Methods as is was before and now its just divided into 3 different methods. One for each event but it looks the same:

```
public void setUpLabelWriterListener(){
        for (int i = 0; i < window.getRow(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < window.getCol(); j++){
                int finalI = i;
                int finalJ = j;
                MouseAdapter writer = new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(rectangleMode){
                            pressed = true;
                            startGrid = new Grid(window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].getGrid());
                            System.out.println("Start: " + startGrid.getRow() + " - " + startGrid.getCol());
                        }
                        else {
                            pressed = true;
                            window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].getPixel().setBackground(color);
                            window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].setPainted(eraserMode);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(rectangleMode){
                            pressed = false;
                            endGrid = new Grid(window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].getGrid());
                            System.out.println("End: " + endGrid.getRow() + " - " + endGrid.getCol());
                            window.writeRectangle(startGrid, endGrid, color);
                        }
                        else pressed = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (!rectangleMode && pressed){
                            window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].getPixel().setBackground(color);
                            window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].setPainted(eraserMode);
                        }
                    }
                };
                window.getPixels()[finalI][finalJ].getPixel().addMouseListener(writer);
            }
        }
    }
```

These prints to the console states the same coordinates which is the puzzling bit.

Comment: *"..which is the puzzling bit."* What is the question (bit)? Also: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Realised I had to move to writeRectangle method to mouseEntered since it doesnt know where it is when mouse is released.

Comment: Now, you might either delete the question, or answer your own question below.